# raspberry pi gpio or rs232 relay board for simultaneous output bit-map?

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio

I really wanted at first an rs232 8-channel relay board that I could command devices to turn on/off with a command string.

All of the ones I found online have the same deficiency in functionality for me: you can't set a subset of relays at the exact time.  I can set relay 1 on, and then relay 7 on afterwards, I can set all 8 relays at once, but there is no command structure to pick out the exact leds I would like to turn on/off.
In the past I have dealt with hardware that had a bit-map of the IO pins, and a bit-map of the states and would apply all 8 settings at once.  here are some examples:

to set pins 1 and 7 to on and the other pins off (8-bit binary bit-mapping,) send the following byte: in binary:    0100 0001b

to set pins 1,2,3,6 to on and the other pins off (8-bit binary bit-mapping,) send the following byte: in binary:    0010 0111b

I couldn't find any such device to do this so I thought I could make one with a raspberry pi using a simple 8-channel relay board, something like this: 
[https://www.amazon.com/SainSmart-101-70-102-8-Channel-Relay-Module/dp/B0057OC5WK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0057OC5WK)

but on a Raspberry Pi, I'm running into the same issue:  I don't see a way to set the gpio pins as a block command, only individually setting them in a for loop. I looked all morning and can see things like gpioctl, and mmio, but I can't put it all together to a simple proof of concept program on a testboard, any help would be appreciated.

I would really like a solution in C or scripting, 
Thanks,

jleslie

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to switch them at the exactly same time? If it's just for driving LEDs, you'll always be fast enough the user won't notice the difference.

Comment: I just am explaining the problem in a simple led example. I have to coordinate exact robotic controls and will be controlling servo motors in a very precise manner.

Comment: You could be trying an Mcp23017 GPIO expander on I2C. This allows setting 8 or 16 pins at once.

Comment: @PFM, many GPIO drivers allow you to do that. There is in-kernel callback `->set_multiple()` and corresponding `libgpiod` API in user space. But note to the OP, define *precise* please. In non-RT OSes this is almost impossible to achieve, especially using user space approach (not in-kernel drivers).

Comment: I will have to try it some more.  the gpio as it is should be fast enough.  Right now I'm comarping a rs232 9600 baud relay controller and the delay between leds' is very noticeable in a windoze scripting environment.   I've been playing with bit-packing multiple relay settings into a single rs232 message and I get better results. I'm guessing its the overhead of the rs232 that is my real issue.